# I can't bypass FRP lock on my Galaxy J5 2016

Tags: samsung, unbricking

I was just following a recommendation of MalwareBytes to encrypt my phone.
So I plugged in the power cable as it said and confirmed my decision. The phone turned off but then there's only a black colored screen that says **"Custom binary blocked by FRP"** and **"secure fail: kernel"**.

*My phone is rooted but there never has been any malfunction. But recently the screen started to turn on every few minutes without any obvious reason. It said something about a Power Sharing app that I could get. I was never able to identify the cause of that problem.*

Just today I reset the developer settings back to normal. Then I tried to make the encryption... That was extremely bad timing.

Odin doesn't recognize my Samsung and I can't use the ADB shell because it doesn't return a serial number or any other life sign.

Restarting doesn't work, it just brings me right back to the FRP lock.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: You should have enabled OEM unlock before, that's why you are getting custom binaries blocked by FRP. What do you mean by Odin isn't recognizing the device and by restarting the Developer Settings to normal?